# How to make "type" not to echo file names when joining multiple files in Windows CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When joining multiple files with

```
type *.xml >> temp.txt
```

The command line (or batch script) would print each file name found on the screen. Is there a workaround to make it silent?

Since I'm adding an extra code on the first line of the `temp.txt` file, I can't use `copy *.xml temp.txt`.

Comment: The file names are output at `STDERR`, your `type` command will not write them to `temp.txt` but to the console; to avoid that also, chage it to `type *.xml >> temp.txt 2> nul`... note that the file contents are written to `STDOUT`...

Comment: Or just `copy A + B + C D`